# Chapter Numbers as text instead of numbers BUT in Russian (Cyrillic)

Tags: numbering, chapters, parts, cyrillic, russian

There's a code to display Chapter 1 in `\documentclass{book}` as "Chapter One" or even "Chapter ONE", I know it. But my problem is that the text I'm currently working on is in Russian (Cyrillic). So instead of `Глава 1` (Chapter 1) I need it to be displayed as text, i.e. `Глава Один` (Chapter One).

Moreover, I'd like it as ordinal numbers, not cardinal. In other words, instead of `Глава Один` (Chapter One) I'd really like it to be displayed as `Глава Первая` (First Chapter).

Is there code to accomplish that? If there is, can it also be applied to Parts (instead of roman numbers)?

Comment: You could do that with the `fmtcount` package, but it  requires a  .def` file for each language, and as there doesn't exist one for russian, you shoulld make one first.

Comment: I’ve just started learning Tex and have no idea what a .def file is. I really doubt that I can create one :-(

Comment: You would just have  to look at some .def file for another language and adapt it to russian, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will not use cross references to the chapters automatically (or keep all the references in nominative case) then you can use the following code. It defines a custom counter representation which prints ordinal numbers, and use it for chapters. The complicated part is to convert a number to the corresponding ordinal. The code works with chapter numbers upto 999 and prints correct chapter numbers in the table of contents. I haven't checked if it works with document classes other than book.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername\ }
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnumb{\newline\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftchapleader{\cftdotfill{1}}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalfont}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\ordinalrussian}[1]{%
  \@tempcnta=\number\value{#1}
  \protect\@print@tempcnta}

\newcommand{\@print@tempcnta}{%
\ifnum\@tempcnta <100
  \ifnum\@tempcnta <20
    \ifnum\@tempcnta >10
      \@tempcntb=\@tempcnta
      \divide\@tempcntb 10
      \multiply\@tempcntb 10
      \advance\@tempcnta -\@tempcntb
      \divide\@tempcntb 10
      \@printtens
    \else
      \@printones
    \fi
  \else
    \@tempcntb=\@tempcnta
    \divide\@tempcntb 10
    \multiply\@tempcntb 10
    \advance\@tempcnta -\@tempcntb
    \divide\@tempcntb 10
    \@printtwenties
    \ifnum\@tempcnta >0
      \ \@print@tempcnta
    \fi
  \fi
\else
  \@tempcntb=\@tempcnta
  \divide\@tempcntb 100
  \multiply\@tempcntb 100
  \advance\@tempcnta -\@tempcntb
  \divide\@tempcntb 100
  \@printhundreds
  \ifnum\@tempcnta >0
    \ \@print@tempcnta
  \fi
\fi}


\newcommand{\@printhundreds}{%
  \ifnum\@tempcnta = 0
    \ifcase\@tempcntb
      --\or
      сотая\or
      двухсотая\or
      трехсотая\or
      четырехсотая\or
      пятисотая\or
      шестисотая\or
      семисотая\or
      восьмисотая\or
      девятисотая\fi
  \else
    \ifcase\@tempcntb
      --\or
      сто\or
      двести\or
      триста\or
      четыреста\or
      пятьсот\or
      шестьсот\or
      семьсот\or
      восемьсот\or
      девятьсот\fi
  \fi}

\newcommand{\@printtwenties}{%
  \ifnum\@tempcnta = 0
    \ifcase\@tempcntb
      --\or
      --\or
      двадцатая\or
      тридцатая\or
      сороковая\or
      пятидесятая\or
      шестидесятая\or
      семидесятая\or
      восьмидесятая\or
      девяностая\fi
  \else
    \ifcase\@tempcntb
      --\or
      --\or
      двадцать\or
      тридцать\or
      сорок\or
      пятьдесят\or
      шестьдесят\or
      семьдесят\or
      восемьдесят\or
      девяносто\fi
  \fi}

\newcommand{\@printtens}{%
  \ifcase\@tempcnta
    десятая\or
    одиннадцатая\or
    двенадцатая\or
    тринадцатая\or
    четырнадцатая\or
    пятнадцатая\or
    шестнадцатая\or
    семнадцатая\or
    восемнадцатая\or
    девятнадцатая\fi
}

\newcommand{\@printones}{%
  \ifcase\@tempcnta
    нулевая\or
    первая\or
    вторая\or
    третья\or
    четвертая\or
    пятая\or
    шестая\or
    седьмая\or
    восьмая\or
    девятая\or
    десятая\fi
}

\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\ordinalrussian{chapter}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

%\chapter{Заголовок \arabic{chapter}}

\loop\ifnum\value{chapter}<999
  \chapter{Заголовок \arabic{chapter}}
\repeat
\end{document}
```

`tocloft` is used to reformat chapters in the table of contents. Without reformatting it's hard to fit long ordinals into the table of contents lines.

Comment: By “planning to reference chapters automatically”, do you mean they won’t be referenced properly in TOC? If you do, then yes, they will be referenced in nominative case only. If I got it all wrong, I’d rather explain what I’m trying to achieve. I’m working on a novel written entirely in Russian. It doesn’t require any special formatting, and I have decided on most of the commands I need. Now I would like to display the chapters in text and subsequently compose the TOC. Given the goal I described, how would you code it properly to compile a perfect novel file?

Comment: Well, as I understand what a novel is, you don't have to use cross reference like `\ref{SomeChapter}` to chapters at all. Also, if the novel is sufficiently long then the number of chapters can be large, so adding them to the `\ifcase` can be tedious. I'll update the answer with code that converts chapter numbers into ordinal Russian numbers up to 999, and makes them work in table of contents.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your work. But it's not working as it's supposed to. I added the first (longer) part of the code in preamble and the shorter code after \begin{document}. It created the whole 999 chapter TOC, then another TOC, and another TOC after that.

Comment: The code after `\begin{document}` is for example only. It creates 999 chapters in a loop. You don't want that in the real document.

Comment: It works perfectly, now when I know how to use it properly :-). Also since you used `\usepackage{tocloft}` how do I modify the settings of the TOC? Say the font and size of the `Оглавление (ТОС)` heading? The position of the page numbers in TOC and etc.? Is it already in the code you provided? If yes, would you please point me to it?

Comment: You could look into the tocloft documentation.

Comment: I will. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry for troubling but it seems like there's another problem I can't overcome without your help. I adjusted you code a bit. Deleted this part `\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnumb{\newline\normalfont}` because it prevented dotted lines from appearing. But now the dotted lines between Chapter Number (Глава первая) for example and its corresponding page number overlaps as far that I can see dotted line start on the last letter of Chapter Number (Глава), through the whole Number (первая) and up until the page number. I can't seem to find a solution for that. Can you help?